# Card not showing when tweeting from iOS app includes image

Tags: ios, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller, twitter-card

My app (Xcode 6, iOS 7 up) uses the in built share sheet to tweet some basic text, an image (screen shot), and a link to a website that has a twitter app card.

When tweeting from the app with an image included I notice the twitter card does NOT appear. When I tweet from the app without an image it works as expected.

Is there a way to include an image and have the twitter card work? I need the twitter card to be the 'app card' type.

I can't find any documentation on this and hoping one of you may have experienced the same issue.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, Have you found anything on this, I have same issue.. :(

Comment: @Dilip Got a reply from Twitter staff, will post as the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer to this question via the [Twitter developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-not-showing-when-a-tweet-from-ios-app-includes-image/25358). Unfortunately at this stage it turns out it's not possible.

Twitter staff reply:
"No, you cannot include both an image and a card in a single tweet for display. As you've found, including the image will cause the card not to be used."